# How to use URL to connect to MongoDB server?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I don't know where to put the URL of the database in MongoDB in this script like `url : mongodb:localhost/mydb`. I cant find any answers in the introduction and tutorials.

```
  var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

  var state = {
    db: null,
  }

  exports.connect = function(url, db, done) {
    if (state.db) return done();

    MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true  }, function(err, client) {
      if (err) return done(err)
      state.db = client.db(db);
      done();
    });
  }

  exports.get = function() {
    return state.db;
  }

  exports.close = function(done) {
    if (state.db) {
      state.db.close(function(err, result) {
        state.db = null;
        state.mode = null;
        done(err);
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: You don't. That file exports functions, one of which (connect) takes the URL as a parameter.

Comment: See the sub-topic _Connect to MongoDB_ at [MongoDB NodeJS Driver Documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/quick-start/quick-start/). Also, see [Connection String URI Format](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can set DB in the option parameter.

```
    MongoClient.connect(url, { db: '' }, function(err, client) {
      ...
    });
```

see https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/mongoclient.html#connect